# String Interpolating of Escaped Characters

Tags: javascript

How can I interpolate a JavaScript string value taken from the DOM?

Say I take a text area with the value `\033[1m\033[0\n\n\033[1;33;42m` as such:

```
var inOne = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
var inTwo = "\033[1m\033[0\n\n\033[1;33;42m";
console.log(JSON.stringify(inOne));
console.log(JSON.stringify(inTwo));
```

And the console:

```
> "\\033[1m\\033[0\\n\\n\\033[1;33;42m"
> "\u001b[1m\u001b[0\n\n\u001b[1;33;42m"
```

How can i achieve `inOne === inTwo` wherein `inTwo` is the true value I want?

This value would be user input and I do not want to evaluate it.

Comment: So the user guesses what inTwo is?

Comment: No. I desire to programatically convert `inOne` in a manner which results in it's equality with `inTwo`.

Comment: Aren't both lines ANSI?

Comment: '\' from textarea is a char '\' i.e. '\\' and not escape char. One way is you use regex to extract eschape char code and convert to string. e.g. /\\([\d]{3})/gi to extract octal number and convert to string using String.fromCharCode(parseInt(num, 8))

Comment: but why would you want someone to type these escape sequences in text area? what's the use case?

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex to parse the escape sequence and convert to corresponding chars in javascript.
A sample code:

```
var r = /\\([\d]{3})/gi;//regex to parse octal numbers
var r2 = /\\([a-z])/gi;//regex to parse escape char sequence e.g. \t, \n etc

inOne = inOne.replace(r, (reg,grp)=>{ 
                             return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp,8)); });

inOne = inOne.replace(r2, (reg, grp)=>{ 
                             return JSON.parse("\"\\"+grp+"\""); });
```

similarly you can include code to handle unicode and hex number parsing as well.